# Why is post() not updating the DOM after it returns? Weird timing problem observed

Tags: jquery, postback, jquery-events

I have the following code that is really bugging me, I'm thinking perhaps the `post()` function needs to be blocking.  I am new to jQuery (latest version) and AJAX, but I'm using ColdFusion which returns some HTML in the data variable.

```
var dataResult;
var statusResult;
$.post('fh_result.cfm',$('#myform').serialize(),function(data,status){
     dataResult = data;
     statusResult = status;
});
//alert(statusResult);
if ('success' == statusResult)
{
    alert(statusResult);
    $('#result').html(dataResult);
}
```

When I uncomment out the first alert, it returns 'undefined' but then it goes into the if block and the next alert box it says 'success'.  If I comment out that line it doesn't make it into the if statement at all.  My guess is that I want to make this a blocking call or something because I want to insert the data on the page after the post.  I also have a problem when I re-write the top code as follows:

```
var dataResult;
var statusResult;
$.post('fh_result.cfm',$('#myform').serialize(),function(data,status){
     dataResult = data;
     statusResult = status;

     alert(statusResult);
     $('#result').html(dataResult);
});
//alert(statusResult);
```

Now in this case, the alert says 'success' when I comment out the second alert box.  When I uncomment it out, I get one alert that says success and the other that says undefined, but this time it updates the DOM with the result of the postback as desired.  How can I do this without the alert box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.post()` runs asynchronously. While it starts to run, the javascript interpreter moves on and runs the `alert()` statement that is outside the `post()` body. Since the `post()` is asynchronous, it will almost certainly not be complete by the time that `alert()` is called, and thus your statusResult and dataResult variables will likely be undefined. Only the code that runs inside the `post()` success callback is guaranteed to run in sequence.

You also might try using the variable provided directly by the success callback, rather than assigning it to another variable originally defined outside the `.post()` block. So:

```
 $('#result').html(data);
```

...instead of dataResult.
Could be a red herring, but worth a try.

Comment: Hum, I see.  So, I had some other code below this that should have been moved up into the success handler.  That's why the DOM insertion was failing.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is functioning as it should.  you cant expect the Ajax call to return immediately.  The post is called and before the return, javascript will continue running the rest of its commands.  The post may return in 1 millisecond, 1 second, or 1 min.  But the code in the call back function of the post will not execute until the post makes a roundtrip from the server.

Comment: OK, I understand that it's an async call, but how do I get the result into the DOM then? Why do I need an alert before it inserts the result into the DOM? I thought an alert() would be non-intrusive, but in this case it's necessary.

I think I should point out that it never inserts the results into the DOM when the alert('statusResult') is commented out.